# To get the url of the page from which external script is called

Tags: javascript, php, url

Suppose there are two websites say `A` and `B`

Now website `A` contains a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://B.com/some_path</script>
```

whose src refers to a php script in Website `B` that outputs valid javascript code

Is there a way to get the url of website `A` from which the script is being called

**Edit:** sorry my bad that I didn't mention that I want the url in the php script and not in the javascript which is the output of php script refrenced from script src

Comment: sorry my bad that I didn't mention that I want the url in the php script and not in the javascript which is the output of php script refrenced from script src

Answer (score 0):

```
document.referrer
```

This is the javascript command that should get the http_referrer string of the page that it was clicked from

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
window.location.href
```

or

```
document.URL
```

to retrieve the URL in your JS code